# Rails ajax call not converting erb elements to html

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, xmlhttprequest, http-status-code-500

There's probably a much better title for this, but I don't what the technical terms would be


Anyway, I'm performing an ajax call that appends a link to a div. The link contains erb code such as

```
#{post.comments.count}

$('#comments_<%= @post.id %>').append("<%= escape_javascript (link_to 'view all #{post.comments.count} comments', post_comments_path(@post), remote: true, class: 'more-comments', id: 'more_comments_#{post.id}', data: {post_id: @post.id, type: 'html', value: '#{post.comments.count}' }) %>"); }`
```

The link ends up looking like this:

```
<br/><br>
view all #{post.comments.count} comments
<br>
<br>
```

This is what the link looks like when inspecting it:

```
<a class="more-comments" id="more_comments_#{post.id}" data-post-id="4" data-type="html" data-value="#{post.comments.count}" data-remote="true" href="/posts/4/comments">view all #{post.comments.count} comments</a>
```

When I try using `<%= %>` in the code, I end up getting 500 errors. With other AJAX links using `<%= %>` I'm not being thrown these 500 errors.

For example:

This works:

```
$('#more_comments_<%= @post.id %>').html("view all <%= @post.comments.count %> comments");
```

This doesn't:

```
$('#comments_<%= @post.id %>').append("<%= escape_javascript (link_to 'view all <%= @post.comments.count %> comments', post_comments_path(@post), remote: true, class: 'more-comments', id: 'more_comments_<%= @post.id %>', data: {post_id: @post.id, type: 'html', value: <%= @post.comments.count %> }) %>");
```

This throws this error:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/posts/4/comments 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I tried circumventing this by 'splicing' the link together with JS held variables:

```
$('#comments_' + Append.id).append("<%= link_to 'view all " + Append.comment_count + " comments', post_comments_path(" + Append.id + "), remote: true, class: 'more-comments', id: 'more_comments_" + Append.id + "', data: {post_id: " + Append.id + ", type: 'html', value: " + Append.comment_count + " } %>");
```

And I'm still receiving the 500 error.

The comments controller looks like such,

```
def index
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comments = @post.comments.all.order("created_at ASC")
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { render layout: !request.xhr? }
            format.js
        end 
    end
end
```

I can't find this exact issue on stackoverflow, I'm probably just not googling (TIL googling is a word) the right key words.
Lots of E-love for those who made it this far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to use ERB tags (`<%= %>`) where you should be using standard Ruby string interpolation (`#{ }`).

ERB tags can only be used in certain places, i.e. `.erb` files.

Furthermore, ERB tags cannot be nested. So in your example,

```
$('#comments_<%= @post.id %>').append("<%= escape_javascript (link_to 'view all <%= @post.comments.count %> comments', post_comments_path(@post), remote: true, class: 'more-comments', id: 'more_comments_<%= @post.id %>', data: {post_id: @post.id, type: 'html', value: <%= @post.comments.count %> }) %>");
```

the problem is the ERB tags inside the escape_javascript method, which should be replaced with standard Ruby string interpolation.

FYI, saying that you have a 500 error is not useful unless you show the actual error. Since 500 is the 'generic' error, it can result from a practically infinite set of circumstances.

Comment: Ahh okay, so I changed this up to look like this: `$('#comments_<%= @post.id %>').append("<%=j link_to 'view all <%= @post.comments.count %> comments', post_comments_path(@post), remote: true, class: 'more-comments', id: 'more_comments_<%= @post.id %>', data: {post_id: @post.id, type: 'html', value: <%= @post.comments.count %> } %>"); }` <br> and I dug deeper into the 500 status and found that it was a `xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null );` From other questions on this it seems like it _may_ be an issue with chrome trying to access local files. Thanks for helping

Comment: This was spit out from the log: `SyntaxError (/Users/jackrothrock/rails/Instagram/app/views/comments/create.js.erb:5: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'
...t_buffer.safe_append=' comments\', post_comments_path(@post)...
...                               ^
/Users/jackrothrock/rails/Instagram/app/views/comments/create.js.erb:7: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')'
/Users/jackrothrock/rails/Instagram/app/views/comments/create.js.erb:9: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'):

Comment: @Jack.Rothrock you're still trying to nest ERB tags. Here for example: `<%= link_to 'view all <%= @post.comments.count %> comments', `. Secondly, don't just paste your code in comments. Include it in a multi-line code block in your question. Thirdly, I can tell you that this error does not relate to `xhr.send` and doesn't have to do with chrome or local files. Try and understand what the error is telling you. See how it says `create.js.erb:5: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')`? That means a closing parenthesis is missing on line 5 of create.js.erb.

Comment: @Jack.Rothrock don't know if you noticed, but I edited your question because your code was not formatted correctly. You can't use `<br>` for newlines in StackOverflow questions ... this isn't HTML.

Comment: Aha, I finally get what you meant. Took me awhile. I just ditched the link_to and used an <a>. The weird thing is, I didn't have any parentheses missing, it was just the <%= %> inside the <%= %> I believe. The reason I used the <br> was because it worked in the previewer, I then saw you corrected it after I submitted my first comment. I'll keep what you said in mind for the future. Thanks again for helping me

Comment: @Jack.Rothrock yeah, "understanding errors" is easier said than done. I think the most common are probably `SyntaxError`, `ArgumentError`, `TypeError`, `LoadError`, and `NoMethodError`, so you'll probably come to recognize those. There are many other error types, though, and I usually google errors I havent seen before. As far as using `<a>` goes - I think that's a good call. I was going to recommend that until I saw that you were using `remote: true`. I use regular `<a>` tags, but I also write my AJAX functions by hand ... I wonder if `remote: true` is easier.  BTW could you accept my answer?

Comment: Of course, yeah I have yet to try any TDD and DDD - that'll be a nice struggle. Yeah I agree, I'm gonna start doing the ajax without rails. I think I may have been able to do it with rails by making an instance variable with the dynamic link, i'm gonna test that now. Anyways thanks again man

Comment: @Jack.Rothrock actually I think TDD is taught a little too early with Rails. It's more productive in my opinion to learn the basics of the language / framework first then work on tests later. You can just use `print` statements for tests.